# Asynchronous indexing by Hibernate Search (HS) after transaction commit

Tags: java, ajax, lucene, hibernate-search

There is REST service which searches and updates data, backed by Hibernate and HS. Lucene index has more than 1.5 million documents and growing.

Problem: when service persists updated data into database (`session.commit()`) - same time HS performs data indexation, As result transaction is committed with a delay (2-5 seconds) - so HTTP response is delayed for data update requests. REST service has a lot of methods and the client side which exists for this service expects that after AJAX call returns - data is available for a 'GET', so committing transaction in async manner on server side - is not an option (data won't be available for client right after POST).

I'm using `hibernate.search.default.worker.execution=async` but this setting helps not much (improvement is about 1 second with it). The reason is that HS gathering data for updated/created documents using current session/thread and then indexing asynchronously to Lucene..

So my questions are: 
1. Is there a way to perform data computation by HS asynchronously to main execution thread? So transaction commit is not frozen for the time of data collection.. 
2. I suppose that with my issue using JMS with Master/Slave won't help much because bottleneck is not indexing itself - but gathering of data to index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently isn't such an option.

In similar situations, I managed to optimise the data access of Hibernate as 2-5 seconds is not very impressive, for example  looking into 2nd level caching, make unnecessary relations lazy (and necessary relations eager). Remember to never make a cached relation eager, or it won't use the cache.

In case you're new to Hibernate, know that it *might* be optimised so to do operations in just a couple of milliseconds; I appreciate though that you might already be an expert and just have lots of complex data, as of course there are limits of what you can obtain with optimisations and then it's fair to look at different patterns.

We could think of making a fully async indexing process but it's quite complex: after you terminate the current transaction, we'd be reading a potentially inconsistent state. A solution would be to re-read the whole object graph in a new transaction: after your transaction is committed, open a new one in a clean session and re-load all necessary data.
It's probably an interesting option to have, but chances are high that your server and databases would suffer from all the additional work such a pattern creates.

I've filed some design thoughts as https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2364

Comment: Thx Sanne, the issue is that we need to re-index 2 000+ documents per some POST (update) request. I think it's natural that data collection takes so much time in this case ~ 2 seconds. This is about 1 ms per document, which I consider OK, since we also have pretty complex relations and large number of related entities which need to be loaded for a document. As a solution we successfully use exactly what you recommending: _"re-read the whole object graph in a new transaction, after your transaction is committed"_, by using Hibernate EventListener and Spring AsyncTaskExecutor.